# 連想配列と配列が組み合わさっているものの中身を表示させたい

Tags: javascript, json, array

下記のjsonのchidrenをすべて表示させたいのですが、どうすればよいでしょうか。
childrenの中にchildrenがあり、childrenの個数が可変でも対応させたいです。

```
{
    "children": [
    {
        "contents": {
            "A": 0,
            "B": 1,
            "C": 2
        },
            "children": [
            {
                "children": [],
                "name": "test03",
                "id": 3
            },
            {
                "children": [],
                "name": "test04",
                "id": 4
            }
            ],
            "name": "test01",
            "id": 1
    },
    {
        "contents": {
            "A": 0,
            "B": 1,
            "C": 2
        },
        "children": [
        {
            "children": [],
            "name": "test05",
            "id": 5
        },
        {
            "children": [],
            "name": "test06",
            "id": 6
        }
        ],
        "name": "test02",
        "id": 2
    }
    ]
}
```

得たい結果

```
 "name": "test01"
 "name": "test02"
 "name": "test03"
 "name": "test04"
 "name": "test05"
 "name": "test06"
```

Comment: 表示する順番が 01 03 04 02 05 06 か 03 04 01 05 06 02 でも構いませんか?

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/298450

Comment: 表示順はそれで大丈夫です！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

提示されているJSONは、多分木に分類される[木構造](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%9C%A8%E6%A7%8B%E9%80%A0_(%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E6%A7%8B%E9%80%A0))です。

もし表示する順番が 01 から 06 の昇順である必要があるなら、幅優先探索をするか、深さ優先探索で`name`を集めてからソートする必要があります。

幅優先探索だと以下のようなコードになるでしょう。`root` が JSON をパーズした結果のオブジェクトとします。

```js
function breadthFirstTraverse(root, callback) {
  const queue = [root];
  while (queue.length > 0) {
    const node = queue.shift();
    node.name && callback(node);
    queue.push(...node.children);
  }
}

breadthFirstTraverse(root, node => {
  console.log(`name: ${node.name}`);
});
```

深さ優先探索で表示順を気にしないなら少々シンプルなコードになります。

```js
function depthFirstTraverse(node, callback) {
  node.name && callback(node);
  node.children.forEach(child => depthFirstTraverse(child, callback));
}

depthFirstTraverse(root, node => {
  console.log(`"name": "${node.name}"`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

上記のJSONオブジェクト`{"children": [,,,]}`からキーが`name`のときの値を取得したいとの理解です。この目標を達成させるために次の２パターンを提案させていただきます。

#### パターン1

このパターンでは、getValuesの関数を用意して、その中でオブジェクト内をスキャンしています。

```js
const getValues = (data, contents = []) => {
  for (let key in data) {
    if (key === "name") contents.push({[key]: data[key]});
    if (typeof data[key] === "object") getValues(data[key], contents);
  }
  return contents;
}
  
const obj = {"children":[{"contents":{"A":0,"B":1,"C":2},"children":[{"children":[],"name":"test03","id":3},{"children":[],"name":"test04","id":4}],"name":"test01","id":1},{"contents":{"A":0,"B":1,"C":2},"children":[{"children":[],"name":"test05","id":5},{"children":[],"name":"test06","id":6}],"name":"test02","id":2}]};
const res = getValues(obj);
res.sort((a, b) => a.name > b.name ? 1 : -1);
console.log(res)
```

#### パターン2

このパターンでは、[JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)を使ってオブジェクト内をスキャンしています。

```js
const obj = {"children":[{"contents":{"A":0,"B":1,"C":2},"children":[{"children":[],"name":"test03","id":3},{"children":[],"name":"test04","id":4}],"name":"test01","id":1},{"contents":{"A":0,"B":1,"C":2},"children":[{"children":[],"name":"test05","id":5},{"children":[],"name":"test06","id":6}],"name":"test02","id":2}]};
const res = [];
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj), (key, value) => {
  if (key == "name") res.push({[key]: value});
});
res.sort((a, b) => a.name > b.name ? 1 : -1);
console.log(res)
```

#### Note

- 実際の`name`の値については分かりませんが、入力値から提示された結果に合わせるために、ここでは`res.sort((a, b) => a.name > b.name ? 1 : -1)`を用意しました。もしも不要な場合は削除してください。